# Github action workflow for triggering a job multiple times based on the content from json files using nested matrix strategy

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, jobs

Does someone know whether we can use nested matrices to achieve the following in the github action workflow?

1. list the json files which we have in our repo (may contain more than 1)
2. read the contents of the file
3. trigger a job (**same job**) with the json object values from the files (**job run should be equivalent to no of objects in all the files**)

Please suggest an alternative approach too.

I have two json files (**test1.json and test2.json**) inside products repo.
The code snippet for my current approach, to trigger my workflow

```
jobs:
  list-products:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - id: set-matrix
        run: |
          echo $(ls products/*.json | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]')
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::$(ls products/*.json | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]')"

  read-file:
    needs: list-products
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
        matrix:
            manifest: ${{ fromJson(needs.list-products.outputs.matrix) }}
    outputs:
      matrix-json: ${{ steps.read_file.outputs.contents }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Read file contents
        id: read_file
        uses: andstor/file-reader-action@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ matrix.manifest }}
      
      - name: Save file contents
        run: echo "::set-output name=contents::${{steps.read_file.outputs.contents}}"

      - name: checking output of the job
        run: echo ${{ toJson(steps.read_file.outputs.contents) }}

  check:
    needs: [ read-file ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
        fail-fast: false
        matrix:
            manifest: ${{ fromJson(needs.read-file.outputs.matrix-json) }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 
      - run: |
          echo "${{ matrix.manifest }}"
```

My json files under the products repo looks like this

test1.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "repo 1",
    "version": "v1.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "repo 2",
    "version": "v1.0.0"
  }
]
```

and test2.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "repo 3",
    "version": "v1.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "repo 4",
    "version": "v1.0.0"
  }
]
```

I am trying to list the products and run the job **check**, where I expect the job **check** to be executed for four times with all the above json values.
But the above mentioned job is triggered **only twice** with either one of the above json files and the other file is simply skipping.